# Permute within a row in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays that are paired meaning that element 1 in both arrays needs to have the same index. I want to permute these elements. Currently, I tried np.random.permutation but that does not seem to get the right answer.

For example, if the two arrays are [1,2,3] and [4,5,6], one possible permutation would be [4,2,3] and [1,5,6].

Answer (score 1):

You can `stack` your arrays and choose a random column for each row using `choice`.

***Setup***

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4,5,6])    
v = np.column_stack((a,b))

# array([[1, 4],
#        [2, 5],
#        [3, 6]])
```

---

```
np.random.seed(1)
choices = np.random.choice(v.shape[1], v.shape[0])
# array([1, 1, 0])
```

Finally, to index:

```
v[np.arange(v.shape[0]), choices]
```

```
array([4, 5, 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=np.array([1, 2, 3])
b=np.array([4, 5, 6])
random_arr=np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(len(a),)) # Generate a random array of 0s and 1s, let's say arr([0,0,1])
a1=random_arr*a + (1-random_arr)*b                  # arr([0,0,1])*arr([1,2,3]) + arr([1,1,0])*arr([4,5,6]) = arr([4, 5, 3])
b1=random_arr*b + (1-random_arr)*a                  # arr([0,0,1])*arr([4,5,6]) + arr([1,1,0])*arr([1,2,3]) = arr([1, 2, 6])
a=a1
b=b1
```

Run 1 of the code above:

```
a
Out[188]: array([4, 2, 6])
b
Out[189]: array([1, 5, 3])
```

Run 2:

```
a
Out[191]: array([4, 5, 3])    
b
Out[192]: array([1, 2, 6])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.choose` :

```
toss=np.random.randint(0,2,len(x))
print(np.choose(toss,[x,y]))
print(np.choose(toss,[y,x]))
#[1 5 6]
#[4 2 3]
```